# Как создать объектный ELF файл с кодом?

Tags: c, ассемблер, elf

Я пишу свой ассемблер RISC-V для Linux на Си. Мне нужно создать объектный ELF файл со сгенерированными машинными инструкциями. Мне нужно знать структуру файла: какие секции нужно создать, в какие поместить код. Где можно узнать больше по этой теме?

Comment: В документации по формату ELF.